# Unity delete object if it hits NOTHING

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, collision

I'm creating a roguelike game and I need to delete a wall right after it's spawning, but only if it's not colliding with objects tagged **Wall+Ground**. I tried the function OnTriggerEnter2D or OnColliderEnter2D, but those only work if the wall is colliding with anything before it continues to touch nothing.
This is the code I tried to adjust, but I don't know a function I could use:

```
public class BlockWall_Destroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag != "Wall+Ground" | other.gameObject.tag != "Player")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is this script attached to? What component does it have?

Comment: You should probably rather use e.g. [`Physics2D.OverlapBox`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.OverlapBox.html) to check if there is any collider within a certain range around your object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnTriggerEnter2D is only called when there is a collision, if there is no collision, it won't run.

As suggested [in this answer](http://answers.unity.com/comments/601092/view.html), you have to wait one frame at the start of your MonoBehavior to know if it has collided or not.

Here's how it would apply to your case:

```
public class BlockWall_Destroyer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool collided = false;

    void Start() {
         StartCoroutine(CheckForCollision());
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Wall+Ground") // (/!\ condition has been inverted here)
        {
            collided = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator CheckForCollision() {
        yield return null; // wait a frame for OnTriggerEnter2D to be (maybe) called
        if (!collided)     // check on the next frame if there was any collision
            Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Cheers!